# Failed to request resource on Google Oauth using laravel with artdarek

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, google-api, single-sign-on

I have searched online for solution to his problem, but i am yet to find a fix. please i need help..

I get this error : 
OAuth \ Common \ Http \ Exception \ TokenResponseException
Failed to request resource.

Below is my code, if i am doing anything wrong then please help spot it... I have tried using my Redirect URL manually but it still gives the same error..

```
public function loginWithGoogle()
{

    $code= Input::get('code'); 

    $googleService = OAuth::consumer('Google');

    if (!empty($code)){

        $token= $googleService->requestAccessToken($code);
        $result= json_decode($googleService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo' ), true);
             if(!empty($result){
                var_dump($result);
             }

    } else {
            // get googleService authorization
            $url = $googleService->getAuthorizationUri();

            // return to google login url
            return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
        }
}
```

Comment: before $token $level = error_reporting(0); and after $result,    error_reporting($level); try like this in if condition

Comment: User, i don't understand you mean.. do you mean     if (!empty($code)){
  $level= error_reporting(0);
  $token= $googleService->requestAccessToken($code);
  $level= error_reporting($level);
  $result= json_decode($googleService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo' ), true);

Comment: you want to avoid errors in your page please follow above code in if condition.

Comment: just refer this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/problem-with-artdarekoauth-4-laravel

Comment: User, i am using artdarek and it has taken care of that already.. its included in the error messsage im seeing.